# Print apostrophe 's symbols inside python3 format() function

Tags: python-3.x, format, output, apostrophe

Please help me solivng problems with output sentence contains apostrophe ‘ symbol wit standard format() function. I take example from chapter 31 «Learning Python, Fifth Edition» by Mark Lutz  2013 with function, instance, method and instance with print overloading — see code and theirs outout below  . Interpreter information - Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44)  [GCC 8.3.0] on linux .
Example code and output with format() and print() functions:

```
def square(arg):                        # Simple functions     def or lambda
    return arg ** 2

class Sum:                             # Calliable instance
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __call__(self, arg):
        return self.val + arg
    
class Product:                        # Bound method 
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def method(self, arg):
        return self.val * arg
    
class Negate:                       
    def __init__(self, val):          # Operator print overloading
        self.val = -val
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.val)
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Sobject = Sum(2)
    pobject = Product(3)
    actions = [square, Sobject, pobject.method, Negate]     # function, instance, method, instance with print() overloading
    table = {act(5): act for act in actions}                # Dictionary comprhension
    for (key, value) in table.items():                      # Printing with format
        print('{0:2} => {1}'.format(key, value)) 
    output print correct first three rows and  raise exceptions when trying print fourth row which contains mean  (-5, <class '__main__.Negate'>) with apostrophe ' symbol
    25 => <function square at 0x7fdba0d64840>
    7 => <__main__.Sum object at 0x7fdba00a8d30>
    15 => <bound method Product.method of <__main__.Product object at 0x7fdba00a8d68>>
    Traceback (most recent call last): TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Negate.__format__
    
    print(table)                                        # using standard print() function
    output is correct without any errors, see bellow:
    dict_items(
    [(25, <function square at 0x7fdba0088d90>), 
    (7, <__main__.Sum object at 0x7fdba00215c0>), 
    (15, <bound method Product.method of <__main__.Product object at 0x7fdba0021390>>),
    (-5, <class '__main__.Negate'>)])
```

I know how print  apostrophe ‘ inside standard print() function  - add the escape character ' to add an apostrophe in a string that is enclosed in single quotes or replace single quotes to double quotes:

```
print('I\'m studying Python') → I'm studing Python
or
print("I'm studying Python") -> I'm studying Python
```

How fix this problem with apostrophe ' symbol  inside format() function?

Comment: What does your example have to do with printing an apostrophe? You need to define a `__format__()` in the `Negate` class that will handle format strings. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__

Answer (score 0):

to  Pranav Hosangadi
Example takes from Chapter 31: "Designing with Classes" pages 952 - 953 - class Negate has only constructor with def **init**(self, val)  and overloading print() with def **repr**(self): and hasn't any additional  overloading  for **format** and other  embedded  method for  objects described in this example. This example in the book has correct output -5 => <class '**main**.Negate'> on the page 953